# keys property doesn't exist on my PushRegistration object

Tags: service-worker, web-push, progressive-web-apps

I'm trying to implement push notifications in a progressive web apps and am using the new Payload support in Chrome.

I'm trying to send the endpoint and keys up to the server, but don't see the keys property on the PushSubscription object...

How do I access the keys so I can send them to the server?

Answer (score 9):

The keys are available, but as you note aren't available directly in that way.

You have the option to either:

1. Call `JSON.stringify(subscription)` which will create a string that includes the serialized keys (which you can then `JSON.parse` if you really want), or
2. Get a particular key with `subscription.getKey('p256dh')`, which returns an ArrayBuffer, and then convert it to a string yourself, for example `btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(subscription.getKey('p256dh'))))`

Note that the first approach creates "URL Safe Base 64" encoded keys while the second creates "Base 64 (non-URL Safe)". While the web-push Node library will accept either encoding for keys you may want to be careful with which encoding you choose for your library.

Comment: You could do something like: `btoa(String.fromCharCode.apply(null, new Uint8Array(subscription.getKey('p256dh'))));`, like https://serviceworke.rs/push-payload_index_doc.html.

Comment: I tried both of these and they have different results. In my experiment the `btoa` approach resulted in `BIG/OUeTvBk0tfplr+eNOh...` while `stringify` resulted in `BIG_OUeTvBk0tfplr-eNOh...`. These are obviously distinct and I  believe this distinction is causing me issues with the web-push library. Any thoughts about the distinction and a possible resolution?

Comment: The difference is standard base64 vs URL-safe base64. With the `web-push` library, you should be able to use both indistinctly.

Comment: Thanks - turned out the issue was that I was using an old version of the we-push library. Everything is working now, glad to hear the library supports either encoding!